# Too many Desktop Enviroments

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

So I have had Ubuntu for a very long time and am a very curious person. Recently I installed LXDE. LXDE worked out fine, I'm actually using it right now and am loving it. But, at the login screen, when you click the circle to choose your environment, Unity, or Default, or Ubuntu isn't there. I think I may have too many.

Comment: There used to be a bug, so when you had too many environments the list didn't enlarge to hold them all.. That would depend on what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type as

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu
```

this will make the Default DE as Ubuntu.

If you want to deal with choosing more desktops environment.

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Then you can find

[image]

there

```
user-session=xubuntu
```

So right now my Default is xubuntu. If you want change it then `lubuntu`,`xfce`,`lxde`,`gnome`,`ubuntu` are other DE's.

to list all installed DE's ,

```
august@august-OEM:~$ ls /usr/share/xsessions
awesome.desktop  cairo-dock.desktop  xfce.desktop  xubuntu.desktop
```